# Get full Height of the window pop-up include title bar in javafx

Tags: javafx-8

How to get full size of height on the window pop-up in javafx.
I have a fxml layout design by sceneBuilder with Height of the pop-up window is 147. when the pop-up show on the pop-up have a title bar of Window.
my problem how to get full height include the title bar.
thank everybody for help.

Comment: [`Window.getHeight()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#getHeight--) gives you the height of the window, including the title bar.

Comment: thank you, i tried and successful!

Answer (score 1):

As James said, `window.getHeight()` gives the height of total window (title_bar + content).

In addition, remember, if your Stage has used `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)` method, then, you shall have to use `scene.getHeight()` which will give the height of the content. As transparent window doesn't have a titlebar, height of the scene will be the height of the window then.